# Setting access token in Mapbox CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, mapbox

I installed the Mapbox CLI using homebrew as described on the [Mapbox CLI Github Page](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-cli-py). However, I am unable to set the API access token using their commands. I tried

```
$ mapbox --access-token longcomplicatedtoken.31231231
```

but it gave me

```
Error: Missing command.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I might try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that this method is only used when you provide a command, like

```
$ mapbox --access-token longcomplicatedtoken.31231231 geocoding "Washington DC"
```

If you just want to set the access token so that you don't have to type it every time, do

```
$ export MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=longcomplicatedtoken.31231231
```

which will allow you to simply type things like

```
$ mapbox geocoding "Washington DC"
```